# Lucene - Boost the documents with a position close to x,y

Tags: java, lucene

How would one go about boosting documents with a location close to a given point in Lucene (I'm using Lucene directly, no solr server)? I don't want to sort by distance, just give matching documents close a point a boost.

I have an awkward implementation working based on CustomScoreQuery, but it requires me to read all documents which makes it slow when the query matches > a few hundred documents.

Comment: what do you mean with "by a given point in lucene"?
can you give code examples how you index data and how you search?

Comment: Sure, the application is basically plotting a journey (A to B to C...) and I use Lucene to provide auto complete of adresses. When the user has entered the first adress I want to use that information to boots adresses close to the previous location as he or she enters location B, C and so on.